# Highlight (and copy) unique values in random subsets of a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Apologies for the long and complicated question. I have attached a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkRzf.png) that should hopefully illustrate what I have.

I have three boxes, each containing 16 items(labelled with RANDOM alphanumerical codes such as FF1234).

I have built a table (Table 1) where the items in each box are grouped in sets (columns 1-6) and subsets (represented as groups of 4 cells, from A1 to D6). E.g. Box1 will have two sets (A and B) and each set will have 4 subsets (A1, B1, C1, D1 for Set A and A2, B2, C2, D2, for Set B).
By design, all items in a set are unique, but the two sets in a box contain the same objects (just grouped differently between subsets).

For my purposes, each subset is deemed as being Positive or Negative in a different table (Table 2). I have some conditional formatting that check Table 2 and highlights the contents of positive boxes in Table 1 in orange. As you can see, positive subsets will always have one item in common (which I have manually highlighted in red for convenience).

What I would like to do is to populate a separate table (Table 3) with every item that is found within two positive subsets of any box of Table 1. Alternatively, some solution that would allow me to automatically highlight the common positive items in each box within Table 1 (as I have done in red) would be sufficient.
As an extra, it would help if the conditional formatting (both orange and red highlighting) could be made to work when cells A5-A8, A9-A12, C13-C16, D17-D20 are merged. I only got it to work repeating the same letters in each cell.

I know this could be achieved using helper tables or extra cells (also potentially hidden), but the reason why I am asking for expert advice is because I would like this to be as clean as possible, i.e. only using the available tables, conditional formatting and macros.

P.S. @Mobus I did not want to overcomplicate my example, but Positive/Negative subsets are determined through other data that is normally entered in Table 2. I.e. for each subset/location in Table 2 (say subset A3 in cell I7), a formula in cell J7 will automatically look at the (omitted) data in K7 and L7 and return Pos/Neg. That is to say, there is no predictable way of telling if a subset will be positive or negative, as the analysis will be repeated every day with different input data. However, if **subset** A3 is found positive, it is almost guaranteed that one of the **subsets** in **box** 2 that have an item in common with A3 (in my example, **subset** C4) will also be found positive by the analysis. Again, which one it will be is completely random.

Looking forward to your brilliant insights!

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: I would love to help, but its hurts my head :) Can you please explain what constitutes a positive or negative box? Or is that determined only by input data placed in table 2? I.e. table 2 is a given, not calculated. Also why are say, B1 and B2 not tagged positive, as they have FF006 in common.

Also do you need to *copy* to table 3 or can the formula reside in tabel3? and perhaps only manually copied and pasted as values somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @Mobus, thanks for your interest in the problem! I am assuming that what you call boxes are what I defined as subsets :) Should have probably thought of a better system, sorry. I have tried to clarify the Pos/Neg calling in a P.S. to my original post. Hopefully it makes sense. Also the formula(s) that populate Table 3 can definitely reside in Table 3. It is actually what I would like to achieve, but not sure how easy that might be without macros or helper tables...